# Possible extension by continuity of the function $f(x,y)=\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{xy^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Determine if the function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{xy^3}$ can be extended by continuity at the limit points of the domain.

My thoughts:

Domain of the function is the set $\mathscr D_f=\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(x,y): x=0\lor y=0\}.$

Since $x^2+y^2$ appears in the numerator, I wrote $(x,y)=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ for some $r>0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi).$

I think the function cannot be extended by the continuity at the limit points of the domain which are in $\Bbb R^2\setminus\mathscr D_f,$ that is, at the points on the axes.

To show the limit of the function at the origin does not exist:

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{xy^3}&=\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos(r^2)}{r^4}\frac1{\cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)}\\&=\frac1{2\cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)},\end{aligned}$$
but this depends on the direction and is not even defined for $\theta=\frac{k\pi}2, k\in\{0,1,2,3\}.$

Now, I looked at the points of a circle of a radius $r>0$.

If $x_0=0, y_0\ne 0$ or $x_0\ne 0, y_0=0,$ denote the corresponding angle by $\frac{k_0\pi}2$ and we have
$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{xy^3}&=\lim_{\theta\to\frac{k_0\pi}2}\frac{1-\cos(r^2)}{r^3\cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)}\\&=\frac{1-\cos(r^2)}{r^4}\lim_{\theta\to\frac{k_0\pi}2}\frac1{\cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)}.\end{aligned}$$

This, again, does not exist.
I believe my answer is incomplete. How should I proceed and improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{xy^3}&=\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos(r^2)}{r^4}\frac1{\cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)}\\&=\frac1{2\cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)},\end{aligned}$$

At $\theta = \pi/4$ you get $$\frac1{2\cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)}=2$$
At $\theta = \pi/6$ you get $$\frac1{2\cos(\theta)\sin^3(\theta)}=8/{\sqrt {3}}$$
Thus the limit does not exist and the continuous extension is not possible.